# can't seem to change window.location.href or window.location

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a legacy application that stores lots of the user's session data in a database and, when the user logs out, or leaves the site, it is coded to clear all that session data out. It does it by using an onunload event to call a javascript function. That function uses multilple statements that set the window.location.href to the paths of a various aspx files that will clear out the data for that particular application...something like this:

```
window.location.href = "/SubDir/SessionReset.aspx"; 
window.location.href = "/AnotherSubDir/SessionReset.aspx"; 
window.location.href = "/ThirdSubDir/ClearData.aspx";
```

I have one problem, and one question.
THE PROBLEM: The statement doesn't seem to be able to change the value in window.location.href. If I do something like:

```
console.log("First: " + window.location.href);
window.location.href = "/Subdir/SessionReset.aspx";
console.log("Second: " + window.location.href);
```

The value of href does not change between the first console log and the second one. The page is not "redirected" to the SessionReset.aspx page, so that code never runs.

THE QUESTION: Would multiple statements setting window.location.href to different values, in succession, even work anyway? It seems like, if the first "window.location.href = " statement were to work, the browser would go to that page, and that would be it. How could it return so the next "window.location.href = " statement could run, and send the browser to the next page. This doesn't seem possible. Am I wrong here?

Thanks for whatever clarity you can provide.

Comment: It is impossible for the page to go to multiple places...

Comment: I think you need to make a XMLHttpRequest and call some functin on the server which does all the cleanup for you. This can be done on the window.onunload event. Else you can open new window before the current window closes and then that page can do the cleanup job and close itself.

Comment: onunload doesn't work in chrome and opera http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

Comment: w3schools is not a reliable reference.

Comment: I have seen the w3schools info about onunload not working. I got around it by using window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = (function(){ CallMyJavascript(); });. That seems to be working. The javascript runs. It is amazing. The code I am working on has been there for YEARS and, as far as I can tell, never worked. Still, I would like to know why the window.location value doesn't change when I set it equal to a new URL. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way more than one location change will work.

You COULD do something like

```
iframe1.location.href = "/SubDir/SessionReset.aspx"; 
iframe2.location.href = "/AnotherSubDir/SessionReset.aspx"; 
window.location.href = "/ThirdSubDir/ClearData.aspx";
```

and have 2 iframes, probably with some timeout inbetween BUT the best way is to call ONE server process that clears all the data

Comment: Yes. I think doing all of this on the server side is definitely the answer. Thanks for your suggestion!